# jqueryMobile fixed div for advertising

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm trying to create a fixed div that is always present above the footer navigation. 
I need this to display advertising.

Everything i tried resulted in a destroyed page so far.

Is there any jqueryMobile-way to create such a fixed content element that doesn't change and is always present?

Comment: Already solved it by creating a div with css fixed at the start of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can set a jquery-mobile element as fixed with:

```
data-position="fixed"
```

An example from an index.html file of mine:

```
<div data-role="header" id="trf2Header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="f">
    <a href="#homePage" data-theme="e">Home</a>
    <h1> <!-- Info Goes Here -->  </h1>
</div>
```

As long as your element has a data-role ("content" is fine) then data-position="fixed" should do the trick.

As for always present, you will have to write it into every page. It does not persist across pages.